# How to fix SocketException while connecting to Telegram Bot API in Java App

Tags: java, proxy, telegram, vpn, telegram-bot

I'm working on my Telegram bot. I know, in my countries Telegram is locked, so I decide to connect to Telegram Bot API through proxy. When I try to run this code:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultBotOptions;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.ApiContext;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException;

public class SharperBotApp {
    private static final String PROXY_HOST = "89.200.150.35";
    private static final int PROXY_PORT = 37499;//TODO

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();

        DefaultBotOptions botOptions = ApiContext.getInstance(DefaultBotOptions.class);

        botOptions.setProxyHost(PROXY_HOST);
        botOptions.setProxyPort(PROXY_PORT);
        botOptions.setProxyType(DefaultBotOptions.ProxyType.SOCKS4);

        try {
            botsApi.registerBot(new SharperBot(botOptions));
        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this stack trace:

```
Jun 12, 2019 11:56:51 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443
Jun 12, 2019 11:56:51 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
Jun 12, 2019 11:56:51 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443
Jun 12, 2019 11:56:52 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
Jun 12, 2019 11:56:52 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443
org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error removing old webhook
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.util.WebhookUtils.clearWebhook(WebhookUtils.java:79)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.clearWebhook(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:25)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi.registerBot(TelegramBotsApi.java:120)
    at bot.SharperBotApp.main(SharperBotApp.java:24)
Caused by: org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException: Unable to execute deleteWebhook method
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:719)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.bots.AbsSender.execute(AbsSender.java:47)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.util.WebhookUtils.clearWebhook(WebhookUtils.java:74)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:129)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:459)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.facilities.proxysocketfactorys.SocksSSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SocksSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendHttpPostRequest(DefaultAbsSender.java:765)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendMethodRequest(DefaultAbsSender.java:761)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:716)
    ... 5 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I googled it and found that people advise to use proxy... But I've already done it! So I decided to use VPN. I installed windscribe on my laptop but then also got this exception. What should I try to do?  Maybe, I'm doing something wrong? (There is Debian 9 installed on my laptop).

Comment: Maybe it will be useful information: when I go to https://api.telegram.org:443 in Google Chrome, it's ok

Comment: Did you finally manage it? Any solutions?

Comment: @PetrAleksandrov, yes, I got it. Below I posted a solution. Check it and upvote if it help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is just to use tor proxy:

```
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.getProperties().put("proxySet", true);
        System.getProperties().put("socksProxyHost", 127.0.0.1);
        System.getProperties().put("socksProxyPort", 9050);
    }
}
```

But previously you should install tor service:

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```